# Change length of array

Tags: c, arrays, return

I'm new in C programming and I'm trying to make a function that sends what is stored in one array character that each time is going to change. So if my array is first "hello" it should send only 5 characters, but if later is "goodbye" it should send 7. What I want to avoid is have to write a lot of characters if I want to extend my array, like in this:

```
int say (buttonpressed){
  char a[11] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
  int i;
  for (i = 0;i<12;i++)
  {
    U2TXREG = a[i];
    while(U2STAbits.TRMT==0);
  }
  buttonpressed = 0;
  return 0; 
}
```

I would apreciate any ideas, thanks!

Comment: can you explain how the program above sends characters? What is `U2TXREG`

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand what you want to accomplish here, if you want to create a dynamic array just use realloc();

Comment: Note that you have buffer overflow, max valid index of `a[11]` is 10.

Comment: @UmNyobe U2TXTREG looks like a hardware register that writes the data it receive into an UART.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the length of your array or use an End-Of-String character (which usually is \x0 - a binary zero).

Answer (score 0):

```
int say (buttonpressed){
  char* a = "hello";
  int i;
  int size=strlen(a);
  for (i = 0;i<size;i++)
  { //rest as before
```

By using a string constant you initialize the array to end with a null (0) char. This can then be used to find the string length using strlen.

I have also just used a pointer to the string constant as you are not modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to explain more what do you want to do.

From what you say I understand that you want to change the size and contents of your array without changing the for loop.

If that's the case you can use this:

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH 12 /* 12 is an example */
int say (buttonpressed)
{
    char a[ARRAY_LENGTH] = { . . . . };
    int i;
    for(i =0; i<ARRAY_LENGTH; i++){
       ...
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the data and the actual size in a struct (similiar to how you would use a std::vector in C++

```
struct vec{
  char data[11];
  unsigned int size;
}
```

Then in your for loop can just loop from i=0 to i

If your array is always going to be a string, a c-style string would be idiomatic in c.  This is just an char array terminated by \0, and test for \0 while looping over the array.